# Leetcode-1996 The number of weak characters in the game

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

problem:
You are playing a game that contains multiple characters, and each of the characters has two main properties: attack and defense. You are given a 2D integer array properties where properties[i] = [attacki, defensei] represents the properties of the ith character in the game.

A character is said to be weak if any other character has both attack and defense levels strictly greater than this character's attack and defense levels. More formally, a character i is said to be weak if there exists another character j where attackj > attacki and defensej > defensei.

Return the number of weak characters.

my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    int numberOfWeakCharacters(vector<vector<int>>& properties) {
        int count =0;
        for(int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<properties.size(); j++){
                if((properties[j][0]>properties[i][0])&& (properties[j][1]>properties[i][1])){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

this is my solution. I don't know why this doesn't work. I basically compared from everyone in O(n^2) way and increment count if found such case.

Testcase:
[[7,7],[1,2],[9,7],[7,3],[3,10],[9,8],[8,10],[4,3],[1,5],[1,5]]

My Output:
26
Expected:
6

Comment: Maybe use a debugger with the test case that fails.

Comment: C++ should be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by solving random online puzzles. Also see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: The description says "2D" but then only uses a single index, meaning it's 1D. Each element is just a pair.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I'll do that too.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This question has nothing to do with digital signature algorithm (DSA).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your algorithm is counting all the *pairs* where one is "weaker" than the other, but that is not what is asked. You should count all the entries (not pairs) that are weaker than **at least one other**. Don't include in the count how many times you found that the same item turned out to be weaker. Just count the fact that it is weaker than **some** other entry.

Answer (score 0):

as it is already mentioned - your problem is that you're counting not the number of weak characters, but how many characters are stronger, i.e. you're increasing variable `count` multiple times per weak character, the simplest fix is to stop evaluation as soon as first stronger one is found:

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    int numberOfWeakCharacters(vector<vector<int>>& properties) {
        int count =0;
        for(int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<properties.size(); j++){
                if ((properties[j][0] > properties[i][0]) && (properties[j][1] > properties[i][1])) {
                    count++;
                    break; // <-- HERE we need to stop
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

this code should pass all tests, but it will fail because of timeout

to actually solve the problem - you need to change your approach to the problem, I'm not going to post fully working solution, but some tips:

1. what if you sort input array? so you will know that all characters past current item are >= in terms of attack power. how can you decrease number of comparisons then?
2. what if beside current attack/defense you will also know maximal defense power which can be found after current item?